# Apache Cordova Android Javascript Callback not being defined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Maybe I am committing a stupid mistake somewhere. I am running on Apache Cordova 2.1.1 and I have a function in a file called `upload.js` which basically shows a camera view and calls a callback function once it is done uploading the photo via an AJAX request.

The method is:

```
   var Upload = {
      // The callback function that will be invoked with either link or error
      callback_func: null,
      // file is from a <input> tag or from Drag'n Drop
      upload: function(file, callback_func) {

         // Set up the callback first
         Upload.callback_func = callback_func;
         // Checking if the file selected 
         if(!file || file.length < 1) {
            console.log("Error no File");
            Upload.callback_func(null, WRONG_FILE_FORMAT_ERROR);
         } else {
            // Upload the file
            // Callup the callback
            Upload.callback_func(img_url, "Success!!");
         }
```

Now when testing in the browser it correctly calls up the callback, however when testing in an **android** device it says that callback_func is `undefined`.

Does anyone have ideas about this?

I call this function as `Upload.upload(self.image_data, self.onImageUploaded);`